# jQuery: scrolling div so that checked radiobutton is horizontally centered to the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML and jQuery code. The idea is that if a radiobutton is checked, the div #kaaviotaulukko should be scrolled to left position of the checked radiobutton. And the checked radiobutton should be horizontally centered to browser window.

The problem is that my current jQuery code does not center the checked radiobutton horizontally.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#kaaviotaulukko input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    var container = $('#kaaviotaulukko'),
      scrollTo = $(this);

    if(scrollTo.is(':checked')) {
      var leftOffset = scrollTo.offset().left - container.offset().left + container.scrollLeft();

      container.animate({
        // scrollLeft: scrollTo.offset().left - container.offset().left + container.scrollLeft()
        scrollLeft: leftOffset
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

And here is my HTML code which is not the cleaned up yet, but hopefully you will get the idea.

```
<DIV id="kaaviopohja" style="width: 100%;">

<div id="kaaviotaulukko" style="white-space: nowrap; position: relative; text-align: center;">
<div style="display: inline-block">
<!--
--><DIV STYLE="DISPLAY:INLINE-BLOCK"><input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-102" /><div style="float:left;width:0">
</div><div class="krs" style="display: inline-block;width:70px">extra
</div></DIV><!--
--><DIV STYLE="DISPLAY:INLINE-BLOCK"><input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-101" /><div style="float:left;width:0">
</div><div class="krs" style="display: inline-block;width:350px">LQ
</div></DIV><!--
--><DIV STYLE="DISPLAY:INLINE-BLOCK"><input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-7" /><div style="float:left;width:0">
</div><div class="krs" style="display: inline-block;width:350px">L4
</div></DIV><!--
--><DIV STYLE="DISPLAY:INLINE-BLOCK"><input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-6" checked="checked" /><div style="float:left;width:0">
</div><div class="krs" style="display: inline-block;width:350px">L3
</div></DIV><!--
--><input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-100" /><div style="float:right;width:0">
</div><!--

--><div style="z-index:99;width:70px;position:fixed;left:0;top:100px;margin:auto;background-color:red"><br />
</div>

<div style="z-index:99;width:70px;position:fixed;right:0;top:100px;margin:auto;background-color:red"><br />
</div>
</div>
</div>

</DIV>
```

EDIT: I think this is what you were aiming for. You just need to work on your `LeftOffset` variable calculations to get the correct `left` value. I have changed `scollLeft` to `left` in the `animate` function because `scrollLeft` only works for scroll bars. I have also absolute position the wrapper.

If this is the sort of thing you are trying to do. It might be better to look in to carousel js plugins.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.kaaviotaulukko input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    var container = $('.kaaviotaulukko'),
        scrollTo = $(this),
        parent = $(this).parent();

    if(scrollTo.is(':checked')) {
      var leftOffset = scrollTo.offset().left - container.offset().left + container.scrollLeft();
      container.animate({
        left: leftOffset
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.kaaviopohja {
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.kaaviotaulukko {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height:30px;
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.field-wrap {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:25%;
}
.field-wrap .krs {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav-left, .nav-right {
  z-index:99;
  width:70px;
  height:20px;
  position:fixed;
  top:100px;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:red;
}
.nav-left {
  left:0;
}
.nav-right {
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="kaaviopohja">
   <div class="kaaviotaulukko">
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="field-wrap">
      <input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-102" value="extra" />
      <div class="krs">extra</div>
     </div>
     <div class="field-wrap">
      <input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-101" value="LQ" />
      <div class="krs">LQ</div>
     </div>
     <div class="field-wrap">
      <input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-7" value="L4">
      <div class="krs">L4</div>
     </div>
     <div class="field-wrap">
      <input name="nappi" type="radio" id="someID-6" checked="checked" value="L3" />
      <div class="krs">L3</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="nav-left"></div>
  <div class="nav-right"></div>
 </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A couple of things you should change which will get you a bit closer to what you want. First change your selector from `#kaaviotaulukko > input` to `#kaaviotaulukko input`, and change your `.each()` function to `.change`. A good way to debug code is to try and output something in your script such as `console.log(radioInput);`.

Comment: I have updated my question. Maybe it is now easier to understand. Anyway, the function `.each()` is the correct one in this case.

Comment: @WizardCoder I changed `.each()` function to `.change`. Now it works better, but the radiobutton will not be centered horizontally. How could I do that?

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: @WizardCoder I'm not trying to center vertically. I'm tring to center horizontally. It seems to me that `container.offset().left` is always 0, why is that so?

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you want in regards to the about horizontal centering. Do you want this animation to occur only on page load or whenever a radio button is selected?

Comment: @WizardCoder Every time when a radio button is selected.

Comment: I have updated my answer.